# Facing issue in session with the upgrade of my application to Spring 4.1.9 and Hibernate 4.3.11

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Facing issue in session with the upgrade of my application to Spring 4.1.9 and Hibernate 4.3.11..Logs are below:

```
[org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate] - <Could not retrieve pre-bound Hibernate session>
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:325)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1003)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be below possible reason:

1) You need to put @Repository  on class of DAO layer where you are trying to access session.

1) You need to put @Transactional below @Repository  on class of DAO layer where you are trying to access session.

3) Your container is not able to find bean definition file where you have declared session factory and Transaction.

Comment: Did not work with Repository and Transactional annotation.

Comment: Container is able to find the bean definition file

Comment: Are you not working with annotations? can you copy some code snippet.

Comment: I am working with annotations only. But every bean definition is getting loaded